# System.IO.File.WriteAllText outputs gibberish C#

Tags: c#, io

I have a simple program in C# that is supposed to output a text file containing a sequence of character separated by commas. I also output the resulting sequence on the console and it looks fine, however, the text file is full of weird character and no commas.

This is the output :

> 㔳㌬ⰵⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰴⰴⰴⰴⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰴⰴⰴⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰰⰰⰰⰰⰳⰰⰰⰰⰴⰴⰴⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰴⰴⰴⰰⰰⰰⰰⰴⰰⰰⰰⰳⰰⰴⰴⰴⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰴⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰴⰴⰴⰰⰰⰰⰰⰴⰴⰴⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰴⰴⰴⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰴⰴⰴⰴⰰⰰⰰⰰⰴⰴⰴⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰴⰴⰴⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰴⰴⰴⰴⰰⰰⰰⰴⰴⰴⰴⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰰⰰⰴⰴⰴⰴⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰲⰱⰱⰱⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰰⰰⰴⰴⰴⰴⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰱⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰴⰴⰴⰴⰰⰰⰴⰴⰴⰴⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰲⰰⰳⰱⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰴⰴⰴⰴⰰⰰⰴⰴⰴⰴⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰱⰱⰱⰱⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰴⰴⰴⰴⰰⰰⰴⰴⰴⰴⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰴⰴⰴⰰⰰⰴⰴⰴⰴⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰴⰴⰰⰰⰰⰰⰴⰴⰴⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰴⰴⰰⰰⰳⰰⰴⰴⰴⰰⰰⰰⰴⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰴⰴⰰⰰⰰⰰⰴⰴⰴⰰⰰⰴⰴⰴⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰱⰱⰱⰱⰱⰱⰲⰰⰲⰱⰱⰴⰴⰰⰰⰴⰴⰴⰴⰰⰰⰴⰴⰴⰴⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰱⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰱⰴⰴⰰⰰⰴⰴⰴⰴⰰⰰⰰⰰⰴⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰱⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰵⰰⰵⰰⰱⰴⰴⰰⰰⰴⰴⰴⰴⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰲⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰱⰴⰴⰰⰰⰴⰴⰴⰴⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰴⰴⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰵⰰⰵⰰⰱⰴⰴⰰⰰⰴⰴⰴⰴⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰴⰴⰴⰴⰰⰰⰰⰰⰲⰰⰰⰵⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰱⰴⰴⰰⰰⰴⰴⰴⰴⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰴⰴⰴⰰⰰⰰⰱⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰱⰴⰴⰰⰰⰴⰴⰴⰴⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰵⰰⰰⰰⰴⰴⰰⰰⰰⰰⰱⰱⰱⰱⰱⰱⰰⰰⰱⰱⰱⰴⰴⰰⰰⰴⰴⰴⰴⰰⰰⰰⰵⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰴⰴⰴⰰⰰⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰰⰰⰴⰴⰴⰴⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰵⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰴⰴⰴⰴⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰴⰴⰴⰴⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰵⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰰⰰⰵⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰰⰰⰳⰰⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰵⰰⰰⰰⰴⰴⰴⰴⰰⰰⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰰⰰⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰰⰰⰰⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴⰴ

This is what is supposed to be outputted

> 35,35,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,
>   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,
>   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
>   0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
>   0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,
>   4,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,3,0,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,
>   4,4,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,
>   0,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,0,
>   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,
>   0,0,0,0,0,2,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
>   0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,0,0,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,3,1,0,
>   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,0,0,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,
>   0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,0,0,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
>   4,4,4,0,0,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,0,0,0,
>   0,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,0,0,3,0,4,4,4,0,
>   0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,0,0,4,4,4,0,
>   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,0,2,1,1,4,4,0,0,4,4,4,4,0,0,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,
>   0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,4,4,0,0,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
>   1,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,5,0,1,4,4,0,0,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,
>   0,0,0,0,0,1,4,4,0,0,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,5,0,
>   1,4,4,0,0,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,4,4,0,0,
>   4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,4,4,0,0,4,4,4,4,0,
>   0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,4,4,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,4,4,0,0,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,5,0,0,
>   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,
>   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
>   4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,
>   4,4,4,0,0,3,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,
>   0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,
>   4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,
>   0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,
>   4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,

As I said, what is supposed to be outputted is the string that is directly passed into File.WriteAllText.
Am I missing something ? I don't understand what i'm doing wrong. It seems to be working sometimes, but with other string it does not. I can find no relation between the sequences that works and those that do not.

Here is the whole code, it's a simple program that read a bitmap and output the sequence depending on the pixel. It's badly & quickly written but it's supposed to work, i see no reason it shouldn't.

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(args[0]);
        Bitmap Map = new Bitmap(args[0]);
        var MapRGB = Map.Clone(new Rectangle(0, 0, Map.Width, Map.Height), PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);

        int height = Map.Height;
        int widht = Map.Width;
        string MapText = height.ToString() + "," + widht.ToString() + ",";
        for (int h = 0; h < height; h++)
        {
            for (int w = 0; w < widht; w++)
            {
                Color currentPixel =
                MapRGB.GetPixel(w ,h );
                if (currentPixel.ToArgb() == Color.White.ToArgb())
                {
                    MapText = MapText + "0,";
                }
                if (currentPixel.ToArgb() == Color.Black.ToArgb())
                {
                    MapText = MapText + "1,";
                }
                if (currentPixel.ToArgb() == Color.Gray.ToArgb())
                {
                    MapText = MapText + "2,";
                }
                if (currentPixel.ToArgb() == Color.Yellow.ToArgb())
                {
                    MapText = MapText + "3,";
                }
                if (currentPixel.ToArgb() == Color.Green.ToArgb())
                {
                    MapText = MapText + "4,";
                }
                if (currentPixel.ToArgb() == Color.Red.ToArgb())
                {
                    MapText = MapText + "5,";
                }
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine(args[0] + " WROKING " + w.ToString() + " OF " + widht.ToString() + " IN " + h.ToString() + " OF " + height.ToString());

            }
        }
        Console.Clear();
        Console.Write(MapText);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/Map.bwn", MapText);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Seeing some code might help.

Comment: We don't understand what you are doing wrong too.

Comment: In any case make sure to read SO founder's article on [Unicode](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: Thank you for the article, I will definitely read it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not absolutely sure but could be an encoding issue. Use the other overload [`File.WriteAllText(String, String, Encoding)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143376(v=vs.110).aspx) which takes a encoding type as argument like

```
File.WriteAllText(filePath, stringMessage, Encoding.UTF8);
```